# Twitter API not working in Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter4j libraries in android for twitter extention, it was working fine but from yesterday it is showing OAthNoAuthorizedException error I dont know why. The error log is

```
E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): Error during OAUth retrieve request token
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:239)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:55)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341):     at check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:1)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-12 20:01:29.743: E/check.com.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(341): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this API version has been expired, if any new version is released, try with that.

Comment: Thanks , it is working with new key but I dont know why old keys suddenly stop working.